# Doxygen print bash file contents

Tags: bash, doxygen

I have a project with bash, python, and C files where I would like to simply print the contents of the bash file in the doxygen documentation.

I am using Doxygen 1.9.4 and my Doxyfile has the following modified settings:

```
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
PYTHON_DOCSTRING       = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = YES
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = sh=C
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = YES
INPUT                  = .
FILTER_PATTERNS        =  *.sh="sh_filter"
FILE_PATTERNS          += *.sh
```

The sh_filter file has the following contents

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "\verbatim"
echo "$(cat $1)"
echo "\endverbatim"
```

After running doxygen, there is nothing that appears in the file reference for the bash file that is within the working directory.

How can I get the file contents to be printed verbatim?

Comment: The question is what is in a `.sh` file and after filtering will there be anything left to document or is it just some commands that don't constitute even a C type of comment as the output from the filter will just have thewords `\verbatim` and `\endverbatim` and the content of the original shell file. Furthermore I don't see where the shell file (`.sh` file) is included, you probably also need `FILE_PATTERNS += *.sh`.

Comment: Right, I forgot to add the FILE_PATTERNS option in my question above (but have edited it to include this). 
The contents of the `.sh` file shouldn't matter. I want to print the entirety of the file irrespective of what is in the file. I thought Doxygen would print everything between the `\verbatim` and `\endverbatim` section, but this doesn't appear to be the case. Is there a simple header to put the verbatim section within to make it appear?

Comment: As you apparently just want to show the code of the `.sh` file and not document the file contents the `EXTENSION_MAPPING`, extra `FILE_PATTERNS` and `FILTER_PATTERNS` are not necessary. I think you should have a look at the `\verbinclude` command..

Comment: I'm still learning Doxygen, but wouldn't `.sh` files be ignored if the `FILE_PATTERNS` option for `.sh` files is not specified? And if it is specified, how will Doxygen know how to process the file?

Comment: It looked to me you just wanted to show the file so no real processing is required, so please readup on the`\verbincude` and the `EXAMPLE_PATH` settings and try in your test project.

Comment: I suppose I need to add that I'm looking to have the file and contents of the file appear in the File List. The last suggestion only has the file contents appear in another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit long for a comment. The construction as requested is quite unusual as normally the purpose is to document routines / variables / classes / namespaces etc and support this with code. In this case the requirement is to just show the contents of the file.
The bests solution I found is to create the filter like:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "/** \file"
echo "\details \verbinclude $1 */"
echo "$(cat $1)"
```

and have the following added to the doxygen settings file:

```
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = sh=C
INPUT                  = .
FILTER_PATTERNS        =  *.sh="./sh_filter"
FILE_PATTERNS += *.sh
EXAMPLE_PATH = .
```

(where the different paths are depending on the local situation)